# When I trying to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 7 restart and wont install

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, windows-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu from USB flash. So I boot from it and the install begins. It works until it ask me which type of instillation I want.

I choose alongside with Windows 7 and then it the computer restarts and Windows 7 runs without Ubuntu being installed! I tried this installation several times and every time I get the same problem. How can I fix this problem and get Ubuntu to install?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this manually, select 'something else' during install and create a partition to install into.

So long as you ignore any NTFS partition you wont hurt Windows, it's not as scary as it first looks. Maybe this will get you further along.

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Also, have you make space for Ubuntu first?